# new GPU op in Tensorflow - Segmentation fault error

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, segmentation-fault

I've created a new op in Tensorflow (TF) and registered it for GPU. Here is part of the C++ file called `pixel_selector.cc`:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

REGISTER_OP("PixelSelector")
   .Input("in: float32")
   .Input("coord: float32")
   .Input("stride: int16")
   .Output("out: float32")

class PixelSelectorOp : public OpKernel {
   public:
       explicit PixelSelectorOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

       void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override 
       {
           // Grab the input tensor
           const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
           const Tensor& input_tensor1 = context->input(1);
           const Tensor& input_tensor2 = context->input(2);
           ...
           std::cout << "Batch size: " << batch << std::endl;
           std::cout << "Depth size: " << depth << std::endl;
           std::cout << "Width size: " << width << std::endl;
           std::cout << "Height size: " << height << std::endl;
           ...
           std::cout << "Num Pixels " << pixels << std::endl;
           std::cout << "Num Coord " << num_coord << std::endl;
           ...
       }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("PixelSelector").Device(DEVICE_GPU), PixelSelectorOp);
```

The file has been then compiled

```
TF_INC=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())')
nvcc -std=c++11 -c -o pixel_selector.o pixel_selector.cc -I $TF_INC -D GOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC
g++ -std=c++11 -shared -o pixel_selector.so pixel_selector.o -I $TF_INC -fPIC -lcudart -L /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/
```

But when running in the TF session I get the following output:

```
Batch size: Batch size: 1111
Depth size: 141
Width size: 300
Height size: 300
Num Pixels 1
Num Coord 3
Segmentation fault (core dump created)
```

which looks to be a concurrent access. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to catch this in gdb and get a stack trace? Without more information, it's hard to tell what's going wrong here.

Comment: @PeteWarden. I extracted the stack trace but I'm not able to understand the reason for the segmentation fault

Comment: @skiera87 could you figure it out